# jQuery datePicker endDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using this particular datepicker script (which is not the one provided in jQuery itself, but they happen to have the sane name)

[datePicker](http://www.kelvinluck.com/projects/jquery-date-picker/)

And in the examples there's an option to only select dates in the past selectables, however, i can't figure out how to set selectables dates in the past INCLUDING today, without trying to fool the datePicker that the end date is tomorrow (which causes the calendar to render tomorrow selectable, but at select it does nothing)

After lot of testing however i've come into some light about the problem, it seems that when you pass the endDate to the script it transform it to string to later again transform it to a Date object, when doing this the script seems to ignore the hour and it simple puts 00:00:00:00 but when checking the max selectable date it gets 12:00:00:00, since the date i'm givin is greater than today it becomes not selectable.

Thanks in advance

PD: Suggestions like "use another calendar then" means too many changes, so i'd rather try to fix the current one.

Comment: Hey, can you please re-create this issue using http://jsfiddle.net/ ; By the way the datePicker you are using is a nice one to use. Cheers.